# Why is the derivation maps an idenpotent element to $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $D:R\rightarrow R$ be a function such that $D(a+b)=D(a)+D(b)$ and $D(ab)=aD(b)+D(a)b$. Let $w\in R$ be an idempotent. Why in this case $D(w)=0$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nice exercise! Compare $D\left(w\right) = D\left(w^2\right) = 2w D\left(w\right)$ with $D\left(w\right) = D\left(w^3\right) = 3w^2 D\left(w\right) = 3w D\left(w\right)$.

Comment: the ring R is it integral domain

Comment: @m.idaya No not need to be

Comment: if $R$ would be an integral domain, the question would be boring, since w could be only 0 or 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need to invoke $D(w^3)$. After computing $D(w^2)$, we can argue like this:

> Given any commutative ring $R$ and an idempotent $w$, we have that
>   $x=2wx$ implies $x=0$.

To see that, multiply with $w$ to get $wx=2wx$, which is equivalent to $wx=0$, hence $x=2 \cdot 0=0$.